# VSO Hosted Build fails with in dotnet restore step on 3rd part references

Tags: git, build, azure-pipelines, syncfusion

I have a .NET Core Web project in VSO that I'm trying to setup a Hosted Build for it.  This project references a 3rd party (Syncfusion) and when the dotnet restore step happens It fails with the following error:

```
Unable to resolve 'Syncfusion.XlsIO.MVC (>= 14.2600.0.32-preview2-final)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.
Unable to resolve 'Syncfusion.Compression.MVC (>= 14.2600.0.32-preview2-final)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.
```

The Build for this is a very basic build.  All I did was take the default VS build definition and added the dotnet restore step after the NeGet restore step.

I did some reading and found 1 thing that said you needed to include the 3rd party stuff in the packages folder in git repository, so I modified and gitignore file to include the 2 Syncfusion nuget folder from the package directory.

The Syncfusion nuget packages are obviously nuget packages, but they are not in the normal nuget.  Locally I had to add a new nuget package source pointing to the Syncfusion URL.

**Edit**
Based on other questions and reading.  I have made the following changes.  First I changed to the Build Steps to be based off of what is listed here (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/ci/build-aspnet-core).  I then removed the Command Line steps and replaced them with the corresponding .NET Core steps.  This makes no difference, just want to list out where I am currently.

I have added a nuget.config to the root of the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!-- remove any machine-wide sources with <clear/> -->
    <clear />
    <!-- also get packages from the NuGet Gallery -->
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <!-- add a Team Services feed -->
    <add key="syncfusion" value="./packages/Syncfusion.Compression.MVC/14.2600.0.32-preview2-final" />
    <add key="syncfusion" value="./packages/Syncfusion.XlsIO.MVC/14.2600.0.32-preview2-final" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

The 2 Syncfusion directories listed above are local nuget packages and are part of the git repo.  I don't know if the path listed above is correct (it is the correct relative path from the nuget.config file (root of the project).

Still when the dotnet restore step runs I get the unable to resolve error.  For some reason I only get 1 error now for XlsIO one.  I do not see the Compression one anywhere in the log

**Final working answer**
The nuget.config file that I got to work is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!-- remove any machine-wide sources with <clear/> -->
    <clear />
    <!-- also get packages from the NuGet Gallery -->
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <!-- add a Team Services feed -->
    <add key="syncfusionCompression" value="packages\Syncfusion.Compression.MVC\14.2600.0.32-preview2-final" />
    <add key="syncfusionXls" value="packages\Syncfusion.XlsIO.MVC\14.2600.0.32-preview2-final" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I was having the same problem using SyncFusion MVC. VS online now includes nuget.exe in build so answers below are unnecessary. Problem is that the nuget build script makes you choose between custom sources or default sources. You can't have both from the build UI, so you have to combine them in nuget conf and check that in to VC. You'd think they would let you use nuget.org globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 3rd part references are in a NuGet server that can access from Hosted agent, you can refer to these steps to add source:

1. Edit/create build definition
2. First way: Add Command Line build step/task before (Tool: Nuget tool path, Arguments: `sources add -name {your feed name} -source {your feed URL} -username [username] -password [password])` Note: you need to add Nuget.exe tool to the source control and map to build agent
3. Another way is that you can include Nuget.config file in the source control (repository) and use this file as the configure file by specify `--configfile [Nuget.Config path]` argument of .Net Core Restore build step/task

Otherwise, you need to include these reference files in the source control (repository)

Comment: I was unable to get that to work.  I created the nuget.config and retried the build and still got the same error, even with the additional nuget path specified.  I then found this URL (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/ci/build-aspnet-core) and went through the steps in here to see if doing the build this way would make a difference, but I get the same error message about Syncfusion here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved by giving the unique key name for the package sources.

First you have added the different NuGet package sources with the same key name twice like “syncfusion”. Hence it show an error in XlsIO NuGet package alone. Then you have changed the key name as “syncfusionCompression” and “SyncfsuionXls”. So, the issue has been resolved.

The key name should be unique in NuGet.Config.